# Visual Studio Database Project - Generating test data on top of reference data

Tags: sql, testing, continuous-integration, database-project

I am adding continuous integration testing to an existing Visual Studio 2010 database project. Right now we have a build that deploys an 'empty' database [dbo].[MyDb] with just the reference data needed such as locales and countries. Right now this is performed using sql files containing insert statements that are run in the post deployment sql build task.

I now want to add another test deployment build that will deploy to another database on the same staging server as [dbo].[MyDb].[Test] with the same reference data but with generated test data that will have foreign keys to the reference data. Database integration tests are then run against that. Because the state needs to be restored for each test, this needs to be as fast as possible.

From what I've tried so far, to generate the test data using Visual Studio's data generation plan it seems I need to get the reference data to a form that can be read by the Databound generator so that it can generate the test data in a way that maintains referential integrity.

The possible options I can think of are:

- Somehow get the data generation plan to read the reference sql files?
- Change the reference sql files to csv files and change the original build to do bulk inserts
- Combine the builds so that the MyDb database is always deployed first and set it as the sequential databound generator source for the test db.

Has anyone got a better approach or can point to a good guide?

I'm not an expert on build scripts so would like to take advantage of tools to do as much as possible. I want to keep things as a Visual Studio Database project but I also have a license for RedGate's SQL Tools if that would make the testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that handling of reference data still isn't supported very well by database projects. This is confirmed by the comments on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/04/01/maintaining-and-synchronizing-your-reference-data.aspx) by Barclay Hill.

At the moment I've gone with the option of having a reference database and using that with a sequential databound generator. Since it doesn't change very often I just deploy it manually and have stopped short of having a whole separate project just for that as I've seen elsewhere.

Hopefully reference data handling will be added to SQL Server Data Tools at some point.